# How to use Text Component in custom Admin form?

Tags: admin, magento2.3, uicomponent, admin-panel, adminform

I am trying to insert simple text to my custom form (not system.xml).

There is a UI component for Form or DynamicRow to show static text:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-text.html

How I try to use it:

```
    ...
    </field>

    <text name="my_text">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Text</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="false">My Text</label>
            <addBefore translate="false">My Text</addBefore>
            <addAfter translate="false">My Text</addAfter>
        </settings>
    </text>

    <field name="i_am_next_field" formElement="textarea">
    ...
```

It seems incorrect way to use this ui component. 
**How to insert text to my form?**

Comment: Where are you trying to add the text? Most ui components for forms have a comment attribute that displays helper text directly underneath that component. Will that help?

Comment: Almost correct! Yeap, I'm trying to add comment ( `<item name="notice" ` ) to dynamicRow. But it's not provided in dynamicRow tempate. For simple fields `notice` works like a charm

Comment: It appears you may have to create a custom template and add a display for a comment so that you can pass it in from the xml.

Comment: As far as I can see template already exists: `magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/text.html`.  But how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1)** Ui component XML

```
-------------------
-------------------
<field name="my_text">                                                                      
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">            
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>         
                   <!-- Assigning a new template -->
                   <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/form/element/mytext</item>
                </item>
             </argument>
        </field>
-------------------
-------------------
```

**step 2)**  /app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/mytext.html

```
<p> My text goes here ................</p>
```

Comment: It achieves the goal to show text. But this approach does not use Text Ui Component. My question was how to use built-in Text component. It seems underdone functionality :(

Answer (score -1):

You may try this.

```
 <fieldset name="MyFieldsetName">
--------------------------
--------------------------

    <field name="my_text">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">MyFieldsetName</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">my_text</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>                        
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
   </field>   
--------------------------
--------------------------
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Not works. It's ordinary input.